# Question from a conservation law example in Evans' PDE book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to fill in some details in an example given in Evans' PDE book, chapter 3.4, example 1 on page 139.  Starting with an initial-value problem for Burgers' equation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} u_{t}+\left(\frac{u^{2}}{2}\right)_{x}=0 &\mbox{in } \mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty) \\
u=g & \mbox{on } \mathbb{R}\times\{t=0\}, \end{cases}
\end{equation}
with initial data
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x\le 0 \\
1-x & \mbox{if } 0\le x\le 1, \\
0 & \mbox{if } x\ge 1. \end{cases}
\end{equation}
The weak solution is that for $t\le 1$:
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x\le t, 0\le t\le 1 \\
\frac{1-x}{1-t} & \mbox{if } t\le x\le 1, 0\le t\le 1\\
0 & \mbox{if } x\ge 1, 0\le t\le 1, \end{cases}
\end{equation}
and for $t\ge 1$:
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x\le s(t) \\
0 & \mbox{if } x\ge s(t)\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $s(t) = \frac{1+t}{2}$.  My understanding is that $s(t)$ should come from the Rankine-Hugoniot condition such that 
\begin{alignat}{2}
\left[\left[F(u)\right]\right] &= \dot{s}\left[\left[u\right]\right] &&\Rightarrow \\
\left[\frac{u_{L}^{2}}{2}-\frac{u_{R}^{2}}{2}\right] &= \dot{s}\left[u_{L}-u_{R}\right] &&\Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{2}\left(1^{2}-0^{2}\right) &= \dot{s}\left(1-0\right)&&\Rightarrow \\
\dot{s}(t) &= \frac{1}{2} &&\Rightarrow \\
s(t) &= \frac{1}{2}t + c.
\end{alignat}
However, I don't see how to obtain that $c=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what happens at time $t=1$, using your formula for $u(x,t)$:
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x< 1 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x > 1 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
The shock formed at this moment at $x=1$. Hence, $s(1)=1$ from where you find $c$.

(By the way) for this PDE, the Rankine-Hugoniot condition is a fancy way of saying: the velocity of shock propagation is the average of fluid velocities before and after the shock.